# How to show gif while loading user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Hello  I have a button and when i click it it loads user control and it tooks a little time. I want to show gif while it is loading. How can i do it?

Edit: I want add usercontrol to panel on background worker.

```
panel3.Controls.Add(hesaplar.Instance);

hesaplar.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

hesaplar.Instance.BringToFront();
```

Comment: What does that snippet have to do with the question?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You wouldn't do that in the code behind. You need javascript like [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-progress-bar-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx).

Comment: It is winforms app. @SteveGreene

Comment: So is my link. You need javascript or jquery to interact with the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the user a .gif animation while loading you can use [Multithreading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx) for parallel executing and [Action Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) to invoke safe GUI updates.
 please see my comments inside the code example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication21
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // show gif on a different thread until LongTask finish executing
            System.Threading.Thread waitThread = new System.Threading.Thread(ShowGif);
            waitThread.Start();
            // start a new thread to execute LongTask() parallel to the waitThread 
            System.Threading.Thread longTaskThread = new System.Threading.Thread(LongTask);
            longTaskThread.Start();
        }

        // put the code of your task that you want to execute in the background in that method
        private void LongTask()
        {
            // long load...
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            // the "long task" inside the method finished to execute - dispose safely the picturebox from the GUI
            panel3.Invoke(new Action(pictureBox1.Dispose));
            // add user control to panel3
            panel3.Invoke(new Action(AddUserControl));
            // promt to screen
            label1.Invoke(new Action(NotifyTaskHasFinished));
        }

        private void AddUserControl()
        {
            UserControl1 uc = new UserControl1();
            panel3.Controls.Add(uc);
        }

        private void ShowGif()
        {
            // use action delegate to update GUI changes from another thread
            panel3.Invoke(new Action(AddGif));
        }

        private void AddGif()
        {
            // show .gif animation inside picturebox1
            pictureBox1.Image = WindowsFormsApplication21.Properties.Resources.raw_demo;
        }

        private void NotifyTaskHasFinished()
        {
            label1.Text = "LongTask() method has finished and user control was loaded";
        }
    }
}
```